# How can I make many radial circles using only CSS?

Tags: css

[image]

I am trying to make this section in the middle of the page.
I could only make a clear background using css. I searched and found something called linear-background. But I still not sure if I can do it.

Can you please help?

Comment: did you also find [radial-gradient()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/radial-gradient()) You can add multiple gradients on top of each other. Alternatively you can just use an SVG as background-image.

Comment: You could do this with a [radial gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/radial-gradient()).

Comment: Thanks @cloned. How can I make an online svg with that shape?
Can I add some other elements above svg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a tool like [CSSGradient.io](https://cssgradient.io/) you can generate a radial gradient that fits your design.  Then you make it the background to your desired element, and change the styling to center the gradient at `right`/`center`.  See below:

```css
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.gradient-container {
  background: rgb(36, 132, 181);
  background: radial-gradient(circle at right center, rgba(36, 132, 181, 1) 0%, rgba(37, 143, 194, 1) 26%, rgba(36, 132, 181, 1) 26%, rgba(37, 143, 194, 1) 46%, rgba(38, 156, 208, 1) 46%, rgba(38, 156, 208, 1) 62%, rgba(39, 170, 224, 1) 63%, rgba(39, 170, 224, 1) 100%);
  height: 35vh;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="gradient-container">
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
  </div>
</body>
```